# Implementing Layers in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am about to implement Photoshop-like Layers in HTML5 Canvas. Currently I have two ideas. The first and maybe the simpler idea is to have a Canvas element for each layer like:

```
<canvas id="layerName" width="320" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layerName" width="320" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 2;"></canvas>
<canvas id="layerName" width="320" height="240" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 3;"></canvas>
```

This way when you draw to a layer -- it actually goes to that "layer". Layers with transparent positions can be seen through to below layers (Canvases). Layer stacking is controlled with `z-index` property.

The second idea is to use a single Canvas element and implement some logic to handle layers like in this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

                var order = 0;

                function drawLayer1() {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
                    ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);
                }

                function drawLayer2() {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
                    ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
                }

                function draw() {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 256, 256);

                    if (order === 0) {
                        drawLayer1();
                        drawLayer2();
                    }
                    else {
                        drawLayer2();
                        drawLayer1();
                    }
                }

                setInterval(draw, 250);
                setInterval(function() {
                    order = 1 - order;
                }, 200);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="256px" height="256px"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code the two layers will change stacking order every 200msec.

So, the question is that which way would be the best way? What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to use a single canvas element and have multiple layers inside it, you might want to look at my library:

- https://github.com/ant512/CanvasLayers

It uses a damaged rect system to reduce the amount of repainting done every time the canvas changes, so not only do you get layers (which can be nested), but you also get optimised redraws.

Comment: @Tek: Thanks!  Link fixed.

Comment: This is surely very pretty, but also (please forgive me) 152 lines of else/if/bracket Hell.  A super minimal example would be handy :)

Comment: @geotheory: There's a step-by-step tutorial, with examples, in the BitBucket wiki.

Comment: Hi. I have to ask you a question. When I need to render multiple video objects that can be added and removed, should I use the library-like, layer system that you have developed in terms of performance?

Answer (score 22):

Using multiple canvases should be faster, because the canvas gets drawn off-screen and then just blitted to the screen by the browser. You put the burden of switching layers on the browser, which just has to move some rectangles of graphics data around.

If you do the layering yourself, you have more control, but the burden is on the JS and the JS engine to do all the work. I would avoid this if I had a choice, but if you're going for layer effects that work on the underlying layers, this might be your only choice.

Comment: What do you mean by `but if you're going for layer effects that work on the underlying layers`?

Comment: he means things like layerModes in photoshop : SCREEN, DIFFERENCE, LIGHTEN, DARKEN etc...

Comment: yes, I just said layerModes because thats what they are called in photoshop: here are a few ways to calculate them http://www.vanderlee.com/tut_fm_mixingmodes.html and http://www.nathanm.com/photoshop-blending-math/

Comment: If you decide to use multiple canvases, you will probably find CSS opacity property handy. You also get layer hiding and moving pretty much for free.

Comment: Definitely use multiple separate canvases unless you need to blend the results together. If you're going to blend the results, you might be interested in my [context-blender](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) library that adds (a subset of) Photoshop-style blend modes for compositing canvases. (See the [README](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender#readme) for the list of currently-supported blend modes, actively being improved.)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the container div relative ought to have prevented that layer-overwrite issue. Try setting the position on the "occluded text" - e.g. if it's currently absolue it will obvious go in the same region as the top left of the relative stuff.

And it's probably obvious but, by the order of divs in the html you can eliminate the use of the z axis. If you want your stuff to be generic (and for other developers too), use the z axis but store a baseline to which you add your layer indices (so that baseline can be tweaked when using other code using z-axis in a problematic way).

Answer (score 2):

Using [jCanvas](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/),see its layer API: http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/docs/layerAPI/