# Will avoid drawing half pixel in HTML5 canvas improve speed?

Tags: html, canvas

I am drawing a sprite (of a ball) on a canvas element. As the ball moves however, the x or y position of the ball may become a fraction, eg. (20.153; 63.638). When canvas is used to draw this image, it attempts to use transparent pixels to make the ball appear in it's position more accurately.

I was wondering whether I should use `Math.round()` before drawing the ball to avoid the transparent pixel stuff, and possibly speeding up the game a lot. Will this help much? The game is a sorta complex pong game.

The image below should help with my explanation:

[image]

Comment: Whether it speeds up depends on the browser's implementation of `Canvas`.

Comment: Can you give the address to play your game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least [this guy seems to believe so](http://29a.ch/2009/5/13/canvas-tag-drawimage-performance). As Gabe mentioned, it depends on the implementation.

Note that some sort anti-aliasing seems to kick in if you are using regular coords (1, 14, etc.). For this reason some guides ([Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/canvas.html) mainly) seem to suggest that you are better off by rending using half pixels (ie. 1.5, 14.5, etc.). I don't know if this makes any difference to performance, though. It's noticeable on render result at least.

You might also want to experiment with various layering schemes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422907/implementing-layers-in-html5-canvas) for more information. Depending on your situation you might want to treat your objects as separate canvases even and just offset them on top of the background.

Alternatively you could try to render it all on one canvas. In this case you have some extra stuff to keep track of. [This library](http://bitbucket.org/ant512/canvaslayers/) seems to handle all the bookkeeping for you.

Comment: Thanks bebraw. I think when I'm done with the game I'll just test out the differences in performance and visual appearance. I think I'll also test it out across different browsers.

Comment: Cool. It would be great if you could publish your findings. Good luck. :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting sprites on separate canvases (or even standard HTML elements with backgrounds).

Comment: For better performances, don't forget to round coordinates with something like this `var x2 = x|0` instead of `Math.Round`

Comment: @Omiod but that's not `round`. That's `floor`.

Comment: You are right. Looks like I can't edit comments btw.