# Javascript Canvas overlapping images from different layer drawings

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-development, globalcompositeoperation

I create a board game mimic in html canvas and help needed.

The game is drawing on the main context from multiple layers.

Currently there are 5 players and each player have 2 cards. If player 1 grab one of his cards to above the another player ( for example player 5 ) card it is beneath the card as the image shows.

I tried to use the `context.globalCompositeOperation` setting to different but it just won't work.

[Player1 moves one of his cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgxK.jpg)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is no control of z-order on the canvas. You can only clean the content and redraw it again. You may also learn about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273280/how-can-i-simulate-z-index-in-canvas).