# How to use the Z-Buffer when drawing images on Processing.js?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, processing.js

How to use the Z-Buffer on Processing.js, so you can set the depth of a image when drawing it?

---

The problem: objects are drawn in incorrect order. What I have tried: I am sorting all my objects every draw frame to get correct results, but JavaScript's sorting doesn't perform well on almost-sorted arrays, so it's both a waste and a bottleneck. Using the z-buffer could be a solution. Couldn't find it on docs, nor googling for "z-index", "depth", "z-buffer" and "depth-buffer".

Comment: The problem: objects are drawn in incorrect order. What I have tried: I am sorting all my objects every draw frame to get correct results, but JavaScript's sorting doesn't perform well on almost-sorted arrays, so it's both a waste and a bottleneck. Using the z-buffer could be a solution. Couldn't find it on docs, nor googling for "z-index", "depth", "z-buffer" and "depth-buffer".

Comment: can you not edit your post?

Comment: @Nix I think the description of my problem is irrelevant / noise to the question, that's why I added it as a comment.

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough, so the extra `noise` is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These discussions may be helpful to you: [HTML5 Canvas set z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165766/html5-canvas-set-z-index), [How can I control z-index of canvas objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250697/how-can-i-control-z-index-of-canvas-objects).

You should draw the objects in the back first, the objects in the front last. Processing.js uses the HTML5 Canvas, which does not have a concept of z-index.