# Chart.js - Horizontal line on Bar chart interferes with tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using Chart.js 2.6 and I have implemented the horizontalLine plugin to show an average value on my bar charts.  It works fine, however when the tooltip displays in the spot where it intersects with the line, it is partially covered by the horizontal line itself.  I'm trying to figure out how to make the tooltip draw ABOVE the horizontal line.

I understand the tooltip is part of the canvas element, and therefore does not have a z-index property.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is what I'm using for my horizontal line plugin.

```
var horizonalLinePlugin = {
    afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {
        var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
        var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
        var ctx = canvas.ctx;
        var index, line, style, width;
        if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
            for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
                line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];
                style = (line.style) ? line.style : "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
                yValue = (line.y) ? yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y) : 0 ;
                ctx.lineWidth = (line.width) ? line.width : 3;              
                if (yValue) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(chartInstance.chartArea.left, yValue);
                    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = style;
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                if (line.text) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = style;
                    ctx.fillText(line.text, 0, yValue + ctx.lineWidth);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
};

Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);
```

... and then I add it to the bar chart options using the following

```
options: {
     ...standard option stuff...
     "horizontalLine": [{
          "y": averageValue,
          "style" : colorOfTheLine
     }]
}
```

Which generates a chart that looks like the one below.

[image]

..however when you hover on a segment of the chart to display the tooltip, and the tooltip is in the path of the horizontal line, it causes the issue seen below.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this solution if you can interfere with the canvas from chart.js files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165766/html5-canvas-set-z-index

Comment: Decided to just use DOM tooltips which solved the whole problem.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach your plugin to the **`afterDatasetDraw`** hook, instead of **`afterDraw`** . This will make the horizontal line to be drawn before the tooltip.

```js
var horizonalLinePlugin = {
   afterDatasetDraw: function(chartInstance) {
      var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
      var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
      var ctx = canvas.ctx;
      var index, line, style, width;
      if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
         for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
            line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];
            style = (line.style) ? line.style : "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
            yValue = (line.y) ? yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y) : 0;
            ctx.lineWidth = (line.width) ? line.width : 3;
            if (yValue) {
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.moveTo(chartInstance.chartArea.left, yValue);
               ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
               ctx.strokeStyle = style;
               ctx.stroke();
            }
            if (line.text) {
               ctx.fillStyle = style;
               ctx.fillText(line.text, 0, yValue + ctx.lineWidth);
            }
         }
         return;
      }
   }
};

Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);

new Chart(canvas, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ["January", "February"],
      datasets: [{
         label: "Dataset 1",
         data: [80, 50]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      horizontalLine: [{
         y: 50,
         style: 'red'
      }]
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Good one, the Github even suggested ordering was the key.

Comment: I personally don't like Chart.js documentation, thank you for saving my day