# When is it faster to clear the whole canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm in the process of building a canvas-based game that will involve a fair number of sprites overlapping each other while in motion.  I'm targeting mobile devices, so performance is a concern.

In my case, there are basically two ways to go about animating the sprites on the canvas:

1. Erase the entire canvas on every frame on which at least one sprite has moved/changed and redraw *everything*.  This sounds pretty standard, from what I've seen.
2. Erase only those sprites that have moved/changed and redraw only those sprites that have moved/changed and those sprites which overlap those sprites which have moved/changed.  Erasing those sprites which have moved/changed will cut chunks out of those sprites which they overlap, so the overlapped sprites will need to be redrawn.

Naively, it sounds like the second option would yield better performance.  Less draw operations equals less work that the machine has to do, right?  However, whereas the first option would involve (potentially) one clearRect() invocation per frame, the second would involve many clearRect() invocations per frame (albeit each one for a significantly smaller rectangle.)  And that's not to mention the overhead of determining what needs to be erased and what overlaps what was just erased.

So, after a bit of reflection, I'm not sure which would be faster.  I'm certain there are situations where the second would be faster, and I'd imagine there are situations where the first option would be faster.

Are there ways to determine now which would be the faster option?  Or is my best bet to implement it both ways and do some benchmarking?

Comment: About what percentage of sprites will move each frame?

Comment: I'd estimate an average of 60%.  The ones that move in a given frame would likely overlap an average of 4 to 6 other sprites at any one time.  Most of the ones that will move frequently (such as every frame) will be quite small (say, 30x30pixels).  Most of the larger ones (up to 85x128pixels) will move much more rarely (once per half-second at most.)  But, of course, the larger ones will be overlapped frequently.

Comment: As the speed of these calls depends on the implementation you should do some benchmark testing with some simple actions and see which one is faster. 
I used clearReact(..) in combination with fillRect(...) for an intensive project (Diagramo) and had no performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this same issue on a smaller scale and had a head-slapping moment when I realized you can separate out the different drawn elements onto different canvases that overlap each other!

One canvas for background, one for character sprites, etc.etc.

Checkout the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422907/implementing-layers-in-html5-canvas) for a full framework for handling this style of drawing.

Comment: Nice answer.  That's a technique I've heard of and one I'm certainly considering.  I wanted to get more information about 1-canvas animation before settling on a multi-canvas solution, though.